# What is the easiest way to check how large my database is (disk-space)?

Tags: linux, mysql

I am using linux.

Comment: Define "how large".  How many records, how much disk space, what?

Comment: @Zoredache - check the tags.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because lacking vital information, such as the database product.  Also demonstrates no effort to research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should think

```
du -sk /wherever/your/db/stores/its/files
```

Should do it. On Unix MySQL, /var/lib/mysql is typical (but not mandatory).

The result will include files not strictly part of your data such as binary logs, etc. But those are usually important to keep.

Comment: Of course if you are using innodb without some additional options you won't be able to identify spaced used by a single table/database simply by looking at the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

du -hcs /var/lib/mysql/*